# What does "The young graduate student was bright and eager, but green to the power of data structures." mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions

The following sentence is from the "The Algorithm Manual" book

> The young graduate student was bright and eager, but green to the
>   power of data structures.

What does the **green to the power of data structures** mean?. Since green is a symbol of fertility, does this mean that the graduate student was good in data structures ?

Comment: ROTFL ! Fertility power of data structures.

Comment: Green is also used to describe something fresh or new (everything in spring is green). So when someone is green, everything is new to them (i.e. they are inexperienced).

Comment: Thanks. It makes complete sense to think green as fresh.

Comment: A related term is ['greenhorn'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greenhorn). And, @BlessedGeek , never underestimate the fertility power of data structures. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Green* in this case means "[immature in age or judgment; untrained; inexperienced](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/green?s=t)". i.e. not experienced with data structures.